# Spanish Curl Php

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I'm extracting a page using Curl, but the spanish characters like ñ or ó, í, etc... aren't extracted correctly during the curl process.

The meta tag for the UTF-8 is set correctly:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
```

The curl code is this:

```
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $html = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
```

And i've tryed a lot of encoding and decoding options after getting the page, but eny of them work properly.

The wrong output of the characters is somthing like this:

> Espa�a, tambi�n denominado Reino de Espa�a, es un pa�s soberano, miembro de la Uni�n Europea, constituido en Estado social y democr�tico de derecho y .

I think that is not a utf-8 problem, and I don't know were it comes from..

Comment: WHERE is that meta tag? If it's in the page you're scraping, that's utterly meaningless to your code. curl is not a browser. it doesn't interpret what it's fetching. it just sucks down some bytes from the specified url and gives them to you. what you do with those bytes is entirely up to you.

Comment: Oh but it IS a utf8 issue.

Comment: the meta tag is in my page and in the page i extract the info from.

Comment: It could be an utf8 issue, but its more like the browser or the server coudn't read the characters properly after getting the page using curl, when i had a utf8 problem another characters or errors apeared insted of this ? simbol